# how to constraint the moving sine wave to the rotating circle?

Tags: animation, transforms, constraints

Can Anybody help to make  animation like in the photo[image]

Comment: could you please tell more precisely what part you're struggling with? Because for the wave you can just move it along X or Y

Comment: How can I make the rotation animation of the whell/ring/ circle with the 2 orthogonal rod attached and this rods are exactly on the sine & cosine wave  , you  can make them dash line also if you because they are like the projection of the point on the border of the wheel.Hope you understood me.

Comment: and what did u try so far?

Comment: Just a small hint, why i didn't provide a blend file: because you ignored my comment with "what did u try so far?" but you could directly comment on my answer: can u provide blend file? And your question didn't provide your blend file as well. I do provide blend files as you can see in other answer like here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273234/physics-setup-to-test-gears-wont-spin, but the person who questioned did provide a blend file as well and did show he did something. I don't know what you did at all. Maybe you just wanted someone else do your work!? and maybe ....

Comment: you even get money for this!? i don't know. I just can assume. But alone for the learning effect you should rebuild it yourself and try it out. if you fail again, ask again and provide your blend file and you will get help. But i feel i bit exploited if you are just providing an image and one sentence as question and even dare to ask for a blend file, sorry.

Comment: i am voting to reopen the question because he didn't want a python solution (i guess because he didn't tag "python") so i provided another (not python) solution here. Thx.

Comment: Sorry for being so late,I didn't notice this critics ,anway here(https://github.com/kebab03/sineRota) you find my model.How ever can you please show the constraints setting please, I don't understand When you say :Give this cylinder a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder.No I don't get paid for this ,I do only for learning.Well in my model the problem is the scale of te 2 sine/cosine because if  Animate the traslation of sine along x axsis and i scale or change it's location to coincide with the vertical rod ,The Cosine wave is displaced and lose scaled.

Comment: why didn't you copy all of my GN instead letting out important nodes? the animation was in GN by the scene time. I didn't keyframe my animation....so why did u?

Comment: Because I didn't  understand :Give this cylinder a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder  & Give your torus a 360 degree rotation animation on the right axis .So I tried to make my self somting that my works. I fell sorry because I wasn't very clear to ask for help.Anyway  Please explain clearly, if you don't mind the sentence :Give a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder &Give your torus 360 rotation on the right axis ,Which right axis? Or you can kindly share you file.It will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: PLease Mrs Chris  have a look once again to https://github.com/kebab03/sineRota  rotae_new.bld  & tell how can I correct my file?Thank  you ,

Comment: One last think ,  Please not that the photo of the GNode is not very clear .If  you can provide a good quality photo  it will help me ,Have a good day .

Comment: Mrs Chris please  explain this lines :: Give this cylinder a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder & Give your torus a 360 degree rotation animation on the right axis .Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your circle, select 2 or more of its vertices and assign them to a vertex group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Create your stick, give it a Copy Location constraint with the circle as Target, select the vertex group, click on the Offset option and put the stick at the wanted position:

[image]

Make the circle rotate (keyframe it at 0° then 360°, press <kbd>T</kbd> to create a linear interpolation), the stick will follow:

[image]

Create your sine waves and synchronise their movement on the rotation

Comment: Thank you for your help Gentelman  .

Answer (score 2):

Your question is....very short - so my answer will be the same.

Create a plane, add Geometry nodes modifier with this node setup:

[image]

Create 4 materials: red, green, blue, gray

Create a torus and three cylinders, move and rotate them as you see in my animation.

Parent this cylinder to your torus:

[image]

Give this cylinder a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder.

[image]

Give this cylinder a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder.

[image]

Give your torus a 360 degree rotation animation on the right axis from frame 1 to 100 and use linear extrapolation.

result:

[image]

Comment: First off alla Thank you very much ,I thought  that  the animation should done by rigging becase the torus has a rod that is inserted into a hollow cylinder that has 2 perpendicular rod on it's outer surface .How ever can you please show the constraints setting please , and if possible kindly share the blender file that you made .Thank you once again.

Comment: Sorry for being so late,I didn't notice this critics ,anway here(github.com/kebab03/sineRota) you find my model.How ever can you please show the constraints setting please, I don't understand When you say :Give this cylinder a copy location constraint of the two right axis to your parented cylinder.No I don't get paid for this ,I do only for learning.Well in my model the problem is the scale of te 2 sine/cosine because if Animate the traslation of sine along x axsis and i scale or change it's location to coincide with the vertical rod ,The Cosine wave is displaced and lose scaled. –